# sql cuando usar nolock

Tags: sql, sql-server

En una consulta realizada con dos tabla existe la posibilidad de colocar nolock ¿Para que se realiza esto?

`FROM tabla1 t1 (nolock) INNER JOIN tabla2 t2`

Comment: Hola ARG RG. Tu pregunta es muy confusa, ¿qué quieres decir con _'realizacionada'_, querías escribir _'relacionada'_ o _'realizada'_? Por otro lado, parece que tu pregunta se puede responder con un SI o NO, ¿ya lo intentaste, tuviste algún problema o error que puedas compartir?

Comment: gracias por la corrrecion , habia realizado la pregunta por que he visto consulta con  inner join que usan nolock . este tipo de pregunta es abierta

Comment: Para volver al estado anterior que no sea nolock, me imagino que se utiliza el sintaxis with(lock) o me equivoco

Comment: si lo estoy tomando en cuenta para mis correciones de objetos de base de datos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La sugerencia de tabla NOLOCK (o su equivalente READUNCOMMITTED) te permite realizar lecturas de datos aunque éstos estén bloqueados por instrucciones de actualización de datos.

Cuando se realiza una instrucción de actualización de datos (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) estos datos son bloqueados por SQL Server hasta que finaliza la instrucción de actualización (o la transacción si la instrucción se encuentra dentro de una). Si intentas ejecutar una instrucción de lectura ésta esperará hasta que los datos se desbloqueen y entonces realizará la lectura y devolverá los datos.

Al utilizar NOLOCK la lectura no espera a que los datos se desbloqueen, realiza la lectura de los datos tal cual están y los devuelve. Esto aumenta la velocidad de respuesta de las consultas pero también disminuye la fiabilidad de los datos.

La consulta podría devolver un dato actualizado por un cambio que luego se echa para atrás por una instrucción de ROLLBACK.

Por lo tanto puedes utilizar NOLOCK cuando quieras acelerar consultas en las que no sea crítica la fiabilidad de los datos devueltos.