# Consideraciones en el uso del JOIN en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema en su uso. Tengo dos tablas en diferentes bases de datos, ambas tablas son idénticas (misma cantidad y nombre de columnas) y la más pequeña está incluida (todos sus registros) en la tabla original.

Ambas tablas me arrojan la misma cantidad de registros cuando hago uso del `WHERE` y le especifico uno de los campos.

Pero el problema viene cuando les aplico el `INNER JOIN` con el mismo criterio en el `WHERE`. Se supone que me debería arrojar una tabla con la misma cantidad de registros como las consultas hechas por serparado, ya que todos los registros de esta tabla están en la tabla más grande, pero me arroja más resultados, a pesar que el campo que uso para el `JOIN` es un tipo `int`(id_cod) que no se repite dentro de las tablas, y el `WHERE` usa un campo tipo `fecha` que si se repite a lo largo de ambas tablas.

No encuentro la razón del porque sucede esto, tal vez por que ambos tablas tienen el mismo nombre en sus columnas.

Ejemplo:

En DB1:

```
select* from MiTabla
WHERE año='2009' and mes='05'
-- 80 000 registros encontrados
```

En BD2:

```
select* from MiTabla
WHERE año='2009' and mes='05'
-- 80 000 registros encontrados
```

Pero con el `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM BD1.dbo.MiTabla t1 (nolock) inner join
     BD2.dbo.MiTabla t2 (nolock)
                on (t1.id_cod= t2.id_cod) 
WHERE t1.año= '2009' and t1.mes='05' 
-- 100 000 registros encontrados
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14382/78). Además, `...y la más pequeña` ¿a qué te refieres?. Las tablas tienen la misma _cantidad_ de datos, pero ¿tiene los mismos datos, es como si fuera una copia de la otra tabla?

Comment: Si, la más pequeña por el nÚmero de registros, que se extrajo mediante una clausula tipo `WHERE`de la tabla mayor, como dices es una copia (en su estructura)

Comment: De pronto 'id_cod' no es único en las tablas, intenta 'select DISTINCT id_cod from MiTabla' en las 2 bases de datos haber si te da menos de 80.000 registros.

Comment: Seguro que no se repiten ids? Prueba comparar los resultados de ambas tablas con estas consultas para verificarlo: `SELECT * FROM BD1.dbo.MiTabla`  y 
`SELECT DISTINCT id_cod FROM BD1.dbo.MiTabla`

Comment: Si tus pruebas son ciertas, la única posible explicación es que `id_cod` tiene duplicados en `BD2`.

Comment: ¿Qué resultado obtienes si agregas las siguientes condiciones a la consulta con `JOIN`: `and t2.año = '2009' and t2.mes = '05'`?
Con el `JOIN` aseguras que se incluyan los registros que tengan el mismo valor en la columna `id_cod` en ambas tablas, con la condición del `WHERE` se limita el resultado solo a los registros de la tabla `t1` que tengan los valores `'2009'` y `'05'` en las columnas `año` y `mes` respectivamente, pero eso no implica que los registro de `t2` también cumplan estas condiciones.

Answer (score 0):

La explicación es que estás utilizando condiciones diferentes.  En las consultas por separado utilizas el criterio: `año='2009' and mes='05'`.  Pero en la consulta integral la condición del `JOIN` utiliza otro criterio: `t1.id_cod = t2.id_cod`, mientras que solo se restringen los registros de la tabla `t1` con la condición `t1.año = '2009' and t1.mes = '05'`.

Si en la tabla `t2` existen registros que compartan el valor de `id_cod` con los registros de la tabla `t1` que cumplen con la condición `t1.año='2009' and t1.mes='05'` van a ser incluidos en el resultado sin importar el valor de `t2.año` y `t2.mes`.

Ahora bien, si cambias la condición del `JOIN` por: `t1.año = t2.año and t1.mes = t2.mes` dejando la misma condición del `WHERE` vas a obtener la cantidad de registros esperada, pero es probable que no coincida el valor de la columna `id_cod`.

Si agregas la columna `id_cod` a las condiciones del `JOIN`: `t1.id_cod = t2.id_cod and t1.año = t2.año and t1.mes = t2.mes` es probable que la cantidad de registros sea menor a la esperada si existen registros en `t1` que no tienen correspondencia en `t2`.

Cuando se analice una consulta SQL es importante recordar que el orden en el que se ejecuta no es el mismo en el que está escrita.  En el caso de la consulta que te genera más registros de lo esperado ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Se inicia con la cláusula `FROM` y se genera la intersección de las tablas unidas por el operador `INNER JOIN`, generando un resultado intermedio que incluye los registros de ambas tablas que cumplen la condición `t1.id_cod = t2.id_cod`.  Si en `t2` hay más de un registro con el mismo valor de `id_cod` que un registro de `t1` o viceversa, se incluyen todos los registros.

   Por ejemplo si en `t1` hay un registro con `id_cod = 1` y en `t2` hay dos registros con `id_cod = 1` entonces el resultado intermedio tendrá dos registros con `t1.id_cod=1` y `t2.id_cod=1`; el registro de `t1` se repetiría para cada registro de `t2` que tenga el mismo valor de `id_cod`.
2. Una vez que se tiene ese resultado intermedio, se filtra de acuerdo a las condiciones de la cláusula `WHERE`.  En este caso se eliminan los registros que no cumplan con la condición: `t1.año = '2009' and t1.mes = '05'`.

   Aquí es donde está la raíz de la discrepancia, ya que la condición de filtrado no restringe los registros de la tabla `t2`.  Por cada registro en `t1` que tenga `año='2009'` y `mes='05'` se van a incluir todos los registos de `t2` que tengan el mismo valor `id_cod` sin importar el valor que tengan `año` y `mes` en `t2`.
3. Finalmente el resultado se proyecta de acuerdo a la cláusula `SELECT`.  En este caso `*` que indica incluir en la proyección final todas las columnas del resultado, normalmente en el orden definido en la estructura de las tablas y siguiendo el orden de aparición de las tablas en la cláusula `FROM`.  En este caso primero todas las columnas de la tabla `t1` seguidas de todas las columnas de la tabla `t2`.

Answer (score 0):

Es por que solo estas haciendo el filtro a una tabla y no a ambas y tu t2 tiene duplicados en la columna id_cod, esta consulta debería darte los 80 mil records

```
SELECT *
FROM BD1.dbo.MiTabla t1 (nolock) inner join
     BD2.dbo.MiTabla t2 (nolock)
                on (t1.id_cod= t2.id_cod) 
WHERE t1.año= '2009' and t1.mes='05' AND t2.año= '2009' and t2.mes='05'
```

Probablemente id_cod no es un valor unico tal vez para hacerlo un valor unico se tiene que combinar con el año